# Make the google's crawler crawl my website correctly

Tags: search, web, web-crawler, authority

If the main functions of my website only can be used after users log in. How can the google's crawler crawl the main functions in my site, then judge the search ranking of my website according to these functions? I have already set up the sitemap including these functions' url, but I thought maybe the crawler will not crawl these functions correctly. Is there any way to rescue the situation without modifying the original authority setting? Or I only can solve this problem by changing the authority setting? Gratefully thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from google's forum:

If the content is behind a login screen, then there's nothing for Google to crawl. Google can't rank these pages in Search because there's no content available to Searchers.

You can't show content to Google but not show content to people who aren't logged in.